# how to change public ip frequently?

Tags: ip, internet-connection, modem

I know if I turn off the modem and turn it on again, I will have a new public IP. Is there any other way to do it automatically and by software configurations or some code? Is there any other way to change IP without VPNs,Proxies, changing the network and ...?

Comment: This sounds like a classical X-Y problem. You have a problem (or you think you have one), came up with a solution, and now you're seeking help by that solution. Given the question itself, I'm almost certain that changing the public ip address is not going to help you in any way. Reason is that if you want to avoid a ban, as administrator, the 3rd time, I would just ban your entire ip-range. If you want to remain anonymous, not gonna happen. With your IP address even if you change it, I find out what your ISP is and one contact and timestamp and they point towards you anyway.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this unless you interact with the modem via command line and it's unlikely any consumer modem would have this feature _(you'd have to use a serial pad or solder to the serial Gnd, Tx, and Rx pins on the modem's PCB, and even then, you'd need to know how to talk to the modem since it speaks a completely different language than routers)_. Without this, the only way to garnish a new WAN IP from the ISP is to: Power off the modem for ~15min to clear it's memory → With router **also** powered off, power modem on and wait 90s for it to fully boot → Power router on

Comment: @LPChip No! I'm trying to make a website traffic bot and I don't know how to use so many valid IPs without vpn, vps, proxies and ... being hidden is not my intention here, at least not for now. please focus on answering the question not accusing or guessing the reason of question.

Comment: @JW0914 thanks. there are some python libraries like UI which can open webview of firmware and reset the modem automatically throw its configurations. at the moment I couldn't make it happen anyway. let me know if you find out anything else. thanks again.

Comment: The WebUI does not clear the memory, it's simply rebooting the modem - in order for the memory to be cleared, it has to be unplugged for ~15m, otherwise it will retain the same WAN IP saved in memory.

Comment: Using a VPN is definitely the easiest route here. You can switch servers or reconnect and you instantly get a new ip addresse.

Comment: Alternatively, consider making a class to get the public ip adress, test that this works, now everywhere in your script call this class rather than using $_SERVER['...']; and inside the class, make it temprarily just use a random ip address, to simulate the change. Every time you call your script, the ip address is generated randomly.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I got your actual problem.

> I'm trying to make a website traffic bot and I don't know how to use so many valid IPs without vpn, vps, proxies and ... being hidden is not my intention here, at least not for now.

What you want to do is create a function in your script somewhere that gets this ip address, and link to this function from everywhere else.

Once you tested that this works correctly, alter this new function and just let it randomly generate an ip address, so you can create the script and test like you want. Each time the script is called, it will have a different number. If the function is called multiple times in the script, make the variable global to the script, test if it was set before, if not set it, if so, reuse that. This would be the real world scenario.

Now, you will be able to fully test and build your script without resetting your internet at all.

IF you are sure that you got your script working and no more modifications are necessary, you can do a few more fieldtests. You revert the original code of getting the public ip address, and you reset your modem. With the new ip address, you test the script. Then you reset the modem and test a few more times, and there you go. All you got what you wanted in the most efficient time possible.